# Using WebClient keeps changing json to text/plain for Content-Type

Tags: c#, http-headers, webclient

I'm using WebClient and I set the headers to JSON yet when I look at Fiddler, it shows text/plain. I do not understand why. I have to use WebClient (older app).

How do I *enforce* JSON to be sent in the request as Content-Type?

My relevant code:

```
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            webClient.Headers.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");
            webClient.Headers.Add("Bearer", token);

//further down to the call...

var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request).Replace(@"\\\", @"\");
                var jsonResponse = webClient.UploadString($"https://{APIHost}{APIAddress}", content.ToString());
```

Comment: Use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) for this.

Comment: @Jimi Does it support sync calls? I had trouble trying to use that too. I do not want async.

Comment: Try the [UploadData()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploaddata) method, using `var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes([Your String]);` to get the byte array to send. -- Btw, why do you have `Replace(@"\\\", @"\")` there? Are you serializing that `request` thing twice, by chance? There's usually no need to replace anything in the serialized string. Also, test with `webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);` or `webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + token);`. What you're using now is not standard.

Comment: @Jimi yes I am, I have it happening twice and so that was a quick fix due to sub classes/hierarchy reasons. It sends extra \ characters if it's not done and makes the request fail

Comment: Well, don't make it happen twice then. Why would you serialize something that's already serialized?

Comment: @Jimi no the API has a complicated search string with its own use of \ in it and the Serializer does not know how to handle.